# Convert SDR image to HDR with python openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, hdr

I wish to do the following in python with openCV to increase the brightness of an image. The aim is to turn an SDR photo into an HDR image (to increase the dynamic range).

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("image.png")
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv_img)
v = v**3 # any function applied to v
new_hsv = cv2.merge((h, s, v))
```

We then get a brighter image.

The problem is that, `v` is only allowed to take values in the range 0-255, and 255 is not bright enough for an HDR image.

How can I increase the brightness beyond 255, any save the image as an hdr image file (in any suitable format)?

Comment: What is the actual purpose of this please? Multiplying the brightness by 3 doesn't actually increase the amount of information in the image.

Comment: ... imagine there were initially 3 brightnesses in your image, say 1, 10 and 100. After multiplying by 3, you have 3, 30 and 300. There are still only 3 brightness values in the image (no new nuances of brightness) and each one is still related to the others by a factor of 10, just as before.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have edited the codes. Of course, we should use more complicated functions. But that's not the main focus. The purpose is to increase brightness contrast of the image to an HDR level.

Comment: I guess the likeliest idea would be to convert to `float` before `cv2.cvtColor()` so that your HSV values fall in the expected range, then after HSV, transform your `V` channel, then save as TIFF or EXR which are both capable of storing floats and more.